How to disable making auto-generated API Keys of Firebase project
Each time I download google-services.json (for Android app) in my Firebase project, there is in Google Cloud → Credentials brand new API key has been created automatically. How can I disable making auto-generated API keys? It seems these newly generated keys are not restricted by an app (any app can call services with new API-key) and this looks like security issue.

Apparently, it is not possible. These auto-generated API keys are being used by the client to make calls to the Firebase-related APIs. Since these APIs are automatically restricted, you may find that not all of them are needed for your use case. You have the option to remove APIs that you don't need.

A newly generated API-keys are not restricted by an app (any app can call services with the new API-key) and this looks like security issue. Edited the post with this details.
